# xcode 4.2 BTStack

Tags: xcode, ios5, bluetooth

I've downloaded BTStack from the Google code page. compiled it and installed the demo via x code. even got it to sign with my developers signature. all's working well, i haven't got a Wii remote but changed one of the files to look for my mac book, it then connects and the mac asks me to enter a key so all's good.

prob is i now want to start a fresh project and implement BTStack. Can anyone tell me what headers i need and how to import them as I'm totally stuck..

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need the headers from the include folder of the BTstack source tree. The easiest way is to add regular CFLAGS like -I/Path/To/BTstack/Folder/include and LDFLAGS like -L/Path/to/BTstack/Folder/src -lBTstack